# How to fix "10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!" error in Angular 1.2 filter?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I've created a **filter** in AngularJS 1.2 that uses the **ShowdownJS** to parse **Markdown** content into HTML:

```
App.filter('markdown', function( $sce ) {
    var converter = new Showdown.converter();
    return function (value) {
        var html = converter.makeHtml(value);
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
    };
});
```

The binding in the templates is done with **ng-bind-html**. This one receives to final HTML content so it's mandatory to show the content:

```
<div ng-bind-html="post.content | markdown"></div>
```

The **filter works** but I get this error in console because **it returns the $sce service** and it **SHOULD** return just the parsed **HTML string**.

```
10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

How can I avoid this in a **filter**? I could not find any method that can can extract the escaped html from the $sce service.

**EDIT**: if I disable the sanitize service in the config I don't get this error even if the code remains exactly the same.

```
$sceProvider.enabled(false);
```

Comment: First start by setting the digestTtl limit to a higher value using the http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScopeProvider. You may execute 11 iterations. But I would not go higher than 20-25

Comment: the filter returns the $sce service.. it should return strings.. that's my problem.. increasing the ttl doesn't solve that problem

Comment: It seems this will be fixed in 1.2 http://www.github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3932 There will be no need cache the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok after some investigation I found that the problem is instances. Every time your filter fires you return another instance. Then the ng-bind-html watcher fires infinitely.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/oDTUUpJBaxnyrb1XA6hq?p=preview)

I added a cache of all trusted values:

```
app.filter('markdown', ['$sce', function( $sce ) {
    var converter = new Showdown.converter();
    var converted = {};

    return function (value) {
      if(converted.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
        return converted[value];
      }

      var html = converter.makeHtml(value);
      var trusted = converted[value] = $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
      return trusted;
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you. The sad part is that this is done with triple brackets in Ember.. {{{ html_value }}}.. The full demo here: [angular blog demo](https://github.com/esgy/angularjs-blog-demo)

Answer (score 1):

I think it has something to do with [ngBindHtmlDirective](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.0-rc.2/src/ng/directive/ngBind.js#L118) watching it and calling $sce.getTrustedHtml on the value.  You can get around it by avoiding `$sce` and using your own directive [(plnkr)](http://plnkr.co/edit/hmZyStoUHAfdXkdlSrXJ?p=preview):

```
App.directive('simpleHtml', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attr) {
    scope.$watch(attr.simpleHtml, function (value) {
      element.html(scope.$eval(attr.simpleHtml));
    })
  };
})
```

Comment: I want it to be an filter though.. :)

Comment: It is in a filter, the `simpleHtml` directive is just a replacement for `ng-bind-html` that doesn't require you to use `$sce` which is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
return $sce.trustAsHtml(html).toString();
```

Comment: If I do that I get this error: Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this error, I was accidentally using a filter on an object instead of a string.